# Element type converting for really long list (converting long to string)

Tags: python, numpy

What is the fastest way to converting all elements of list from long type to string?

I have:

```
x = [long(1.123), long(45.123), long(124.124124), ...]
```

and need:

```
    x = ['1.123', '45.123', '124.124124', ...]
```

I don't want to iterate over whole list and covert each element (it will be quite slow).

I'm thinking about using a `numpy` array. What you think about that?

Comment: `map(str, x)`? Why do you want to do this, anyway?

Comment: Friend of mine needed that. I will compare numpy and map().

Comment: How many times or how often will the operation be executed and how many items need to be converted?

Comment: It was needed for more than 100 000 000 items and used several times.

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate somehow, and it could be quite fast:

```
>>> lst = [123, 456]
>>> map(str, lst)
... ["123", "456"]
```

or similarly

```
>>> [str(num) for num in lst]
... ["123", "456"]
```

Anyway, be aware, that `long(1.123)` is `1L`.

Comment: Yeah this was going to be my answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

My fast comparison (IPython):

```
x_list = range(10000000)
def list1():
    y = map(str, x_list)

%timeit list1()
```

**1 loops, best of 3: 2.37 s per loop**

```
import numpy as np
x_numpy = np.arange(10000000)
def list2():
    y = x_numpy.astype(str, copy=False)

%timeit list2()
```

**1 loops, best of 3: 992 ms per loop**

Like we see second option is faster. What you think? :)

Comment: But you end up with a different type of object. Accessing individual strings from the NumPy array will be slower, if that's what you are going to do next.

Comment: If your final container needs to be a list, ```list(np.arange(n).astype(str, copy=False))``` is slower than ```map(str, range(n))```.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. <type 'str'> or <type 'numpy.string_'>, both work for me. I needed only fast conversion.

Comment: Sure, that's a good point @wwii. I compared list and numpy array. However, even with 'y = list(x_numpy.astype(str, copy=False))' second option was faster, I tested it a couple of times.